# PECL install pdo_sqlsrv - cannot find config.m4

Tags: php, ubuntu-10.04, pecl, sqlsrv

Im trying to install **pdo_sqlsrv** on  **Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS** with PHP version **PHP 5.4.39-1+deb.sury.org~lucid+2**

**Im running:**

```
pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

**Got this error message:**

```
downloading pdo_sqlsrv-3.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download pdo_sqlsrv-3.0.1.tgz (123,911 bytes)
.....................done: 123,911 bytes
17 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the 
top level source directory    of the module

If the command failed with 'phpize: not found' then you 
need to install php5-dev packageYou can do it 
by running 'apt-get install php5-dev' as a root
userERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I Have installed **php5-dev** package. I seems that the downloaded pdo_sqlsrv package does not contain any **config.m4** file or is missing

**pdo_sqlsrv-3.0.1 package files list:**

```
config.w32
core_conn.cpp
core_init.cpp
core_results.cpp
core_sqlsrv.h
core_stmt.cpp
core_stream.cpp
CREDITS
pdo_dbh.cpp
pdo_init.cpp
pdo_parser.cpp
pdo_sqlsrv.h
pdo_stmt.cpp
pdo_util.cpp
README.TXT
sqlncli.h
template.rc
version.h
```